# Trying to make an electrostatic battery charger

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, generator, electrostatic

Can the DC layout charge a battery? I see as if it is in a solar cell format. I know that for a solar cell, when light hits the cell an electron is discharged but the semi conductor only lets it go in one direction. Here the diodes only let the charge go in one direction. If the insulators had 2000V and the conductor picked only 10% and the motor switched charges from postive to negative every 7milisecnds thats 60 revolutions per second, can it charge a battery?

Imagine the charged plastic rods are in a vacuum and not losing charge.

[image]

Comment: *imagine the charged plastic rods where in a vacuum and not losing charge.* - no need to use imagination; the rod WILL lose charge and you will NOT have created energy for free.

Comment: @user196845 If trying to generate an electro static potential, it would first be good to deterimine how many volts and how many amps you need. There are many ways to generate voltage, look and see what has been done and what hasn't. Van de graff generators work on the principal above, but don't generate much current. Any process that deals with triboelectric charging (frictional charging) is lossy and loses a lot of energy to heat.

Comment: what do you think @Voltage Spike

Comment: What do you think @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75

Answer (score 1):

Insulators are great for storing charges but not for low voltage “high” current and thus low impedance like a 15 Ohm LED when conducting 10 to 20mA.

Therefore using electrostatic insulator materials would  make a poor generator. (NG!)

Comment: Magnetic transformers stepdown voltage and stepup current while capacitive transformers do the same with 2 C ratios but your impedances are too high to be an effective power generator

Comment: Compute size of C for energy transformer and you will see the light why magnetic transformers work far better

Comment: @Brian Drummond - you asked for the purpose of this. i have always wanted to create a continuous capacitor. think of it as lining up many capacitors & discharging them rapidly one after another to create a continuous current with high power output. i see this as a way of doing it. since the insulators provide the potential difference in the conductors, the motor helps to switch charges which acts as a discharging capacitor in conductor. outputting it a AC has issues also Potential difference & current might be high for charging batteries. Can a Buck dc convertor connected 2 it make it usable.

Comment: Benjamin Franklin tried to capture the massive energy in a cloud for obvious use. It was futile both to reach a cloud and to find a material that could be stored as fast as discharge. Your question has a similar false assumption on theory and practical. Keep studying how things work before trying to invent

Answer (score 1):

**can it charge a battery?**

Yes. Just not very well.

Electrostatic machines are extremely inefficient at moving electrons. They typically produce high voltages at very low currents. Connecting a circuit like yours would cause the battery to clamp the output voltage to the battery voltage - but it would not increase the current. To make things worse, some battery chemistries such as lithium-ion don't respond well to that sort of treatment.

Some types do, notably the old standby lead-acid batteries.

Back in the 30s, farms would sometimes take advantage of this. Long runs of metal wire, such as barbed wire fencing, can develop high-voltage, low current charges due to changes in the earth's electric field over distance or wind-induced static. A farmer could maintain a trickle charge on a lead-acid battery by connecting to a strand of bob-wire. Of course, if it started raining the battery would start discharging, but this was typically done in the mid-West and West, where the weather was dry most of the time. The battery was typically used to run a radio at night.

Comment: if the conductor is not getting electrons from insulators. i think it produces more electrons. i thinks the movement of electrons from insulators to conductors is what makes current limited. thats why in this setup there is no contact. to produce high voltage on insulator i used voltage multiplier and insulator in capacitor format. that means potential different does not build like in a van de graff or air on fence. it is there. i dont have tools to complete the whole experiment because of where i am. but current seems to be there at every switch of charge. thats y im asking @WhatRoughBeast

Comment: for a van de graff. if current is discharged it takes a long time to build potential difference again. in this format. potential difference is built again every 7 miliseconds. the challenge i have for this is i cant build a space of less than 1mm between conductor and insulator to rotate at this speed where i am so i have ask.

Comment: @user196845 - Sorry, but you are making less and less sense. A van de Graff generator does not produce an AC voltage, so I don't see how it applies to your drawing. And your talk of "7 milliseconds" doesn't make any sense either. For that matter, I know of no reason why "a space of less than 1 mm between conductor and insulator" would matter. Frankly, I suggest you close this question, then post another question with much more detail about what you are trying to do, what you have done, and the results of your efforts. I suspect that consulting with a native English speaker might help, too.